# How to append external link (font) icon on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

Is it possible to use jQuery to scan all links and then **append** an [external link (font) icon](https://developers.google.com/style/url-links#out-page) to all `<a>` elements with existing `target = "_blank"` property, but only on **hover**? (These does not have to be external links, just links that opens on a new tab.) If possible, **easing** on appearance of the icon would be preferred.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hover` function on link. For icon, use `font-awesome`:

```js
$("a").hover(function() {
    // Add your code inside if condition if you want to check target = '_blank' attribute
    // var attr = $(this).attr('target');
    // if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    // }
    $(this).attr('href', 'https://www.google.com'); //Your URL internal or external.If you don't want manual URL, add desire URL on data attribute and take URL from there.
    $(this).addClass('fa fa-link');

  },
  function() {
    $(this).attr('href', '#'); //Your URL
    $(this).removeClass('fa fa-link');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a target='_blank' href='#'>Link</a>
```

[Check other icons of fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/).